# MigLayout alignment of elements

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, miglayout

[image]

the code that i have:

the JPANEL

```
JPanel dadosdaparte = new JPanel(new MigLayout("fillx"));
```

adding to JPANEL

```
        dadosdaparte.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Dados da Parte"));
        dadosdaparte.add(lblnomedaparte, "span, split 2");
        dadosdaparte.add(tfnomedaparte, "growx, wrap");
        dadosdaparte.add(lblnacionalidade, "split 7");
        dadosdaparte.add(cboxNacionalidade);
        adicionaNacionalidades();
        dadosdaparte.add(lblcirg);
        dadosdaparte.add(tfcirg);
        dadosdaparte.add(lblcpfcnpj);
        dadosdaparte.add(tfcpfcnpj);
        dadosdaparte.add(cpfcnpjinvalido, "wrap");
```

the miglayout cheat sheet or help, i just saw the positioning of the cell, not the alignment of the itens inside the cell, if someone can help me, i appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [MiG Layout Quick Start Guide](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf):

> Components that are alone in a cell can be aligned within that cell,
>   if there is space left over. You can specify this in the column/row
>   constraints to get a default align for the components and/or you can
>   specify it in the component's constraints.

For instance, the following code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("fillx"));
panel.add(new JLabel("Very long label:"), "");
panel.add(new JTextField(20), "wrap");
panel.add(new JLabel("Short 1:"), "right");
panel.add(new JTextField(20));
panel.add(new JLabel("Short 2:"), "right");
panel.add(new JTextField(10), "wrap");
```

Will produce this outcome:

[image]

You can also define the component's alignment as a column constraint, if you know how many columns you will have. The following will produce the same outcome as previous one:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("fillx","[right][][][]"));
panel.add(new JLabel("Very long label:"), "");
panel.add(new JTextField(20), "wrap");
panel.add(new JLabel("Short 1:"), "");
panel.add(new JTextField(20));
panel.add(new JLabel("Short 2:"), "");
panel.add(new JTextField(10), "");
```